# An integrator design

Tags: integrated-circuit, adc, design, integrator

I am trying to build a dual slope ADC by designing the op-amp in transistor level.I am getting an exponential output. I would like to know how to get a linear output in the integrator?[![First image is the output, 2nd graph is the input signal][2]][2]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi26Ou.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Please learn to draw circuits conventionally and use colours  and at a size that we can actually see.

Comment: This gets my vote as possibly the worst drawn and unintelligible circuit diagram I've ever seen.

Comment: @Andy: reminds me of the 'what not to do' from the art of electronics.

Comment: Ahhh a book I sadly have never read!

Comment: Pritha, we all try to be helpful here, but its near impossible with the diagram and explanation you're providing. Please don't be offended by the lack of help. Let this be an educational moment and realize that presenting and explaining a circuit can require as much effort (and sometimes more) then the effort required to design it. Modern software tools often let us quickly try ideas with little time invested. But describing that design is a skill every bit as important as your electronics prowess, and no simulation tools can help there.

Comment: Redraw your diagram using the schematic editor available, that will ensure that we can see it. No answers will be forthcoming until that's done. While you are redrawing, make sure that ground is to the bottom, +ve to the top, signal flow predominantly left to right.

Comment: I have drawn the circuit using the editor. The only difference is the op amp is the not the op-amp used there. I have designed my own op-amp(folded cascode). sorry for the confusion. But this how I simulated my circuit in cadence. My question is how to obtained a linear curve instead of the exponential curve at the output of the integrator.

Comment: Why have you chosen such large resistor values and small capacitor value?

Comment: I used them due to fabrication size issue. It is difficult to fabricate large capacitance. Resistances are the poly resistances.. and can be easily fabricated as they lie on a different layer.

Comment: @PrithaChatterjee -- your second image failed to include properly

Answer (score 1):

First I'm surprised that circuit works at all. The input of the first OpAmp is at ground, and usually in ICs ground is 0V and there's no voltage lower than that. It's difficult for an inverting amplifier to operate around 0V, because the output can't go below that voltage. Maybe you are using a macro model, that would explain the behavior.

Your integrator has two 15M resistors and an 8pF capacitor. If we omit the capacitor for a second, this is a simple inverting amplifier with a gain of -1. For a step of 1V at the input the output will be at -1V. The opamp sinks a current of 1V/15M at its output.

Ok, now we put back the capacitor and assume that it is completely discharged. The opamp still sinks 1V/15M but now the current charges the capacitor. As the voltage across the capacitor rises, more and more current flows through the resistor. The voltage exponentially approaches the final value of -1V.

The conclusion is, that a switch is required instead of a resistor to initially discharge the capacitor.

A typical circuit would look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your R and C values are too high and too low respectively for a practical circuit. Those values will be largely offset by the opamp input resistance and capacitance, resulting in a circuit which behaves very differently from what you expect.

Go for lower R value and higher C value, and bear in mind that the rule of dumb wants R1 to be significantly smaller than R3, unless you have actually calculated both values from the desired frequency response.